# spring boot app in docker image error Connection to localhost:5433 refused

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, docker

I try to learn docker and I made a simple Spring boot application which I'mm trying to dockerize.
I also use PostgreSQL image from Docker hub. The application works only when I run it from IntellIJ but when I run the image resulted from Dockerfile I get an error.

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ADD target/spring-boot-jpa-postgresql-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "app.jar"]
```

The application properties:

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/postgres
spring.datasource.username= postgres
spring.datasource.password= admin


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation= true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= create
```

When I created the postgres container I ran the following command:

```
docker run --name posttest -d -p 5433:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin postgres
```

One question here, if I use the 5432:5432 port mapping, I can't create a connection using external software like DBeaver (It tells me that Connection timed out) and also the Spring app does not work when I run it from IDE. But if I use 5433 or anything else, it works, why?

Now, my main question. How to run the image resulted from dockerfile such that application to work?

I get the image mvp:v4 and I ran this command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 mvp:v4
```

and I get the erors:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5433 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:303) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar!/:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar!/:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:225) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar!/:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar!/:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar!/:42.2.18]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) [hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar!/:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) [hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar!/:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43) [hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar!/:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.jdbcStatement(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:77) [hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar!/:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:53) [hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar!/:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375) [hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar!/:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359) [hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar!/:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:241) [hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar!/:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154) [hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar!/:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126) [hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar!/:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112) [hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar!/:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:145) [hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar!/:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) [hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar!/:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:316) [hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar!/:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:469) [hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar!/:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) [hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar!/:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) [spring-orm-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) [spring-orm-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:231) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar!/:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:95) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar!/:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar!/:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar!/:42.2.18]
        ... 34 common frames omitted

2022-06-18 21:57:40.977  WARN 1 --- [         task-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
2022-06-18 21:57:40.977 ERROR 1 --- [         task-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Connection to localhost:5433 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

I mean, I know that I should use the postgres container name from docker ps command instead of localhost, but how? If I just replace localhost with the container name in application.properties I get an error.

Again, the app works fine when I run it from IDE. I want to run just with the docker image.

Comment: localhost - the container you are in, you are looking for host.docker.internal - the host of the docker (your localhost)

Comment: Thank you, it's working now, in application.properties I replaced localhost with host.docker.internal but now the app starts just from running the image. If I start the app from the app, I get an error. Is there a solution to make both ways to work?

Comment: add a flag (property in the application.properties) to your app, use the flag to select if you are using localhost or host.docker.internal.

Answer (score 2):

Just turning my comment to answer, so this issue can be marked as answered.
When you are running a container (docker) then:

- localhost - the container you are in.
- host.docker.internal - the host of the docker (your localhost).

So, when ever you are trying to call the localhost you should use `host.docker.internal`.
If you sometimes run in container and sometimes as a stand alone,
you need to use a flag of some kind (spring profile/property), and use it to select the appropriate host.